# Number of specific letter in string

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to make a hangman game (with only 6 letter words) and I'm trying to write the code for when there is more than 1 of a certain letter (inputted by the user) in the word

```
    tries = 0
    n = 0
    word = random.choice(word_list)
    print(word)
    while  tries<10:
        guess = input("Input a letter: ")
        if guess in word:
            n = n + 1
            print("Correct. You've got,", n,"out of 6 letters.")
            if n == 6:
                print("You guessed correctly, the word was,", word)
                break
        elif word.guess(2):
            n = n + 2
            print("Correct. You've got,", n,"out of 6 letters.")
            if n == 6:
                print("You guessed correctly, the word was,", word)
                break
```

although the program continues after a double letter is inputted for guess (eg. 's' in 'across') it still doesn't add up the correct number in the 'n' variable

Comment: It may help: https://trinket.io/python3/5e26836adf https://stackoverflow.com/a/55494835/797495

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-the-number-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Also it seems that you're not checking if a letter has already be chosen by the user so you could actually win by spamming one correct letter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count()` for that. Use it to get the number of occurence in the word. This returns 0 if character is not present in word. Like inside your `while` after `input()` -

```
c = word.count(guess)
if c:
    n += c
    if n == 6:
        print("You guessed correctly, the word was,", word)
        break
    print("Correct. You've got,", n, " out of 6 letters.")
```

You may want to check whether user input is indeed a character and not a string or `''`(empty string). That may confuse the program. Also you are not incrementing `tries` variable. So, user may get unlimited turns to try

Also, what is `word.guess(2)` in your code. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to remove letters that have been guessed already. You can do this using the replace function. Like so:

```
tries = 0
n = 0
word = random.choice(word_list)
word_updated = word
print(word)
while  tries<10:
    if n == 6:
        print("You guessed correctly, the word was,", word)
        break
    guess = input("Input a letter: ")
    if guess in word:
        n += word_updated.count(guess)
        word_updated = word_updated.replace(guess, "")
        print("Correct. You've got,", n,"out of 6 letters.")
```

Answer (score 0):

i took the liberty to implement this

```
import random          

from collections import Counter

attempt = 0
tries = 10
correct = 0
character_to_check = 6
word_list = ['hello','hiedaw','rusiaa','canada']
word = list(random.choice(word_list))
print(word)
dic = dict(Counter(word))
while attempt <= tries:
    if correct==character_to_check :
        print("You guessed correctly, the word was {}".format(word))
        correct = 0 

        break

    guess = str(input("enter a letter "))
    if len(guess)>1 or len(guess)==0:
        print("only 1 letter")
    else:
        if guess in word:
           if dic[guess]>0: 
               correct += 1
               dic[guess]-=1
               print("you have guessed correct, you got {} out of {} letter".format(correct, character_to_check))
           else:
               print("already guessed this character")
    attempt+=1
    if attempt>tries:
        print("attempt exceed allowed limit")
```

output

```
['r', 'u', 's', 'i', 'a', 'a']

enter a letter 'r'
you have guessed correct, you got 1 out of 6 letter

enter a letter 'r'
already guessed this character

enter a letter 'u'
you have guessed correct, you got 2 out of 6 letter

enter a letter 's'
you have guessed correct, you got 3 out of 6 letter

enter a letter 'i'
you have guessed correct, you got 4 out of 6 letter

enter a letter 'a'
you have guessed correct, you got 5 out of 6 letter

enter a letter 'a'
you have guessed correct, you got 6 out of 6 letter
You guessed correctly, the word was ['r', 'u', 's', 'i', 'a', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

A funny and unreadable one-liner could do the whole trick:

```py
print(globals().update({"word": __import__("random").choice(['collection','containing','random','words']), "checked" : set(), "f" : (lambda :  f.__dict__.update({"letter" : input("Input a letter:\n")}) or ((checked.add(f.letter) or (print("Good guess!") if f.letter in word else print("Bad guess..."))) if f.letter not in checked else print("Already checked...")) or (print("You guessed correctly the word " + word + "!") if all(l in checked for l in word) else (print("Too many attempts... You failed!") if len(checked) > 10 else f())))}) or f() or "Play again later!")
```

(Do not use in production code probably)

I am using a `set` to remember both attempted letters and number of attemps, no need for another variable.